# Mongodb - Update multiple array element inside JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I have an collection doc like .

```
{'_id':1,
             'name':'Root',
             'taskId':1,
             'parentId':"",
             'path':[1],
             'tasks':[  {"taskId":3,parentId:1,name:'A',status:'Created'},
                        {"taskId":4,parentId:1,name:'D',status:'Created'},
                        {"taskId":5,parentId:4,name:'B',status:'Created'},
                        {'type':'project' , 'proRef':2},
                        {"taskId":6,parentId:3,name:'E',status:'Started'},
                        {"taskId":7,parentId:6,name:'C',status:'Stopped'}]

            }
```

Now I want to update multiple array element field ‘status’ to ‘Deleted’  which is inside JSON  .Let us assume for taskId 3,4  I need to update status to Deleted . I have tried this query with $in with query($) but it is updating very first element is  $in array  only.  In below query only taskId with 3 is getting updated not 4.

```
db.projectPlan.update({"_id": 1,'tasks.taskId': {$in :[3,4]}} , {$set: {'tasks.$.status': 'Deleted'}}, {upsert: false, multi: true});
```

How to update multiple elements in single query.Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This is not possible as outlined in @Gergo 's answer. Your schema suggests you're looking at some sort of project management/planning tool in which case you'll probably want to have tasks in a seperate collection regardless as there are many use-cases where you'd want to query tasks individually (tasks assigned to person X, taks with status Y, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible, it's a limitation of MongoDB. From the documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/):

> $ Acts as a placeholder to update the first element that matches the
>   query condition in an update.

See this ticket for more details: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

It's possible though in MongoDB shell:

```
db.projectPlan.find({"_id": 1}).forEach(function(plan) {
  plan.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    if(task.taskId in { 3: 1, 4: 1 }) {
      task.status = "Deleted";
    }
  });
  db.projectPlan.save(plan);
});
```